# Reference Object from another Subscription Azure Powershell

Tags: azure, powershell

I need to use this Powershell script but the storage account that I need to use is in a different subscription that the SqlDatabase so when I pass the name it wound find it in the current susbcription. How can I reference that object from another subscription in the parameter
-StorageAccountName??

Thanks for your help

```
Get-AzSqlDatabase -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -ServerName $SQLServer `
| Where-Object {$_.DatabaseName -ne "master"}  `
| Update-AzSqlDatabaseVulnerabilityAssessmentSetting `
    -StorageAccountName $StorageAccountName `
    -ScanResultsContainerName "containerlogs" `
    -RecurringScansInterval Weekly `
    -EmailAdmins $true `
    -NotificationEmail @("xxx@mail.com" , "yyy@mail.com")
```

Comment: Maybe in this scenario (different subscriptions) you need to create a SAS URI and use the `-BlobStorageSasUri` parameter instead of `-StorageAccountName`. [Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.sql/update-azsqldatabasevulnerabilityassessmentsetting?view=azps-8.3.0#example-2-update-vulnerability-assessment-settings-with-blob-storage-sas-uri]

Comment: DId you try the `BlobStorageSasUri` parameter as suggested by @holger?

Comment: Yes I tried with the SasUri but it does not work :(